# React js Context is not load properly

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am using a provider for some of that pages in react js. My routes look like this:

```
const pages = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Page 1',
    component: (
      <MyContextProvider>
        <Pag1 />
      </MyContextProvider>
    ),
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Page 2',
    component: (
      <MyContextProvider>
        <Pag2 />
      </MyContextProvider>
    ),
  },
{
    id: 3,
    name: 'Page 3',
    component: (
        <Pag2 />
    ),
  },
];
```

Inside these pages i am using a hook that uses the context.

```
const useMyContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(MyContext);

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useMyContext must be used within a MyContextProvider');
  }

  return context;
};
```

When i open pages all works, but when i do some changes in my code editor and save this, then i get 'useMyContext must be used within a MyContextProvider' in console. If i referesh page again works fine. 
 Why this happen and how to prevent this error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving `MyContextProvider` in the component itself?

```
import { MyContextProvider } from './yourPath';

const Pag1 = () => {
  // ...

  return (
    // JSX
  );
};

export default () => (
  <MyContextProvider>
    <Pag1 />
  </MyContextProvider>
);
```

and your pages array will simply be

```
const pages = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Page 1',
    component: <Pag1 />,
  },
  // ...
];
```

Comment: But, it will not be the same?